# Significance of imaginary mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, mass, quantum-gravity, potential

Can real mass be thought of as producing a deformation in spacetime leading to a stable equilibrium (valley curve in gravitational potential energy) of the massive body, and imaginary mass as similar, but providing an unstable equilibrium (hill curve in gravitational potential energy)?

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if GR has mathematical results of this sort. (Also, I'm very sure they are unphysical ones. Imaginary mass particles have their velocities greater than $c$)

Comment: Wikipedia has a good introduction to imaginary masses. The question, however, is my own thought.

Comment: If someone can tell me the appropriate tags I shall update them.

Comment: More on [imaginary mass](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22imaginary+mass%22).

Comment: Is my analogy appropriate?

Comment: In general relativity there is no such thing as imaginary mass. But I think that the general relativity tag is OK, but what you are asking about requires using the field of quantum gravity. In classical GR energy is always positive, and there are no imaginary numbers anywhere.

Comment: I didn't add a general relativity tag. I'll update them in case someone has changed them